# 1-5 MHz PWM signal generating but how?

Tags: pwm, frequency

I need to generate a PWM signal that I could change the frequency of it between 1 MHz and 5 MHz. I don't know how to do it. And I have to change the amplitude of PWM between 6-10 V.

So I thought that I could use a MOSFET and MOSFEET DRIVER. I could drive MOSFET DRIVER by using STM32 microcontroller. But what kind of MOSFET should I use and in terms of frequency which parameters should I care while choosing MOSFET that could switch in those frequency range.

Thank you so much! Please mind that I'm a student so kind of new for designing this circuits.

Comment: Depends on what you need the PWM output to do. A dry PWM signal is very different from PWM to a 100A motor.

Comment: What is the minimum pulse width? Are there requirements for maximum rise and fall time? How accurate must the output voltages be? How do you plan to change the amplitude? How much current will the PWM signal provide?

Comment: There’s a number of questions you’ve posed. Firstly, consider how your microcontroller generates pwm. Basically it is a counter and a comparator. For a 1MHz pwm with 8 bit resolution you’d need a clock signal 2^8 times 1000000 = 256MHz. For 5MHz, you’d need 5 times that. I don’t think the average STM32 would achieve that.  Either relax your requirements or look for a different technique like the classic ramp generator and analog comparator to generate the pwm. For the mosfet, detail your requirements and iterate. Manufacturers like Infineon have app notes that will lead you through the process

Comment: Is it a one-of-a-kind lab project? Can you accomplish what you're doing with a signal generator?

Comment: You can check the circuit that i am planning to set from given link below. The PWM signal will be digital pwm signal. I am going to use that PWM for water electrolysis. I need 2 A current For electrodes. When it comes to rise and fall times there is no exact numbers but we need a proper PWM . And the for the duty cycle also i could change between 0 and 100 The circuit is here : https://www.hizliresim.com/a10chwg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as *generating* (your question) a logic-level signal with that resolution, there are [some MCUs](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru924f/spru924f.pdf) which combine analog and digital techniques to (say) generate a 2MHz PWM with 11 bits of resolution. That's a resolution of 180ps. Picoseconds.

Doing something useful with that logic-level output is another matter- there will be propagation delays and rise/fall times in whatever the logic-level output is connected to. Maybe a fast MOSFET driver with a lightly loaded output would work for you, you would have to compare your requirements (which you have not fully divulged) with what the chips can do. Typically tens of nanoseconds delay and rise/fall so you won't get the same waveform out of the driver as goes in.

You might want to add a bit more to your question as to what you are actually planning on doing with the PWM. PWM is a great solution for some problems, but if you get too high (or too low) in frequency it can become difficult, uneconomic, impractical or even impossible to use it.

Comment: I will tell you what I need exactly; I need a proper PWM signal that I can change duty cycle and frequency between 1 MHz - 5 MHz. Also I need to change the voltage of PWM between 6-10 Volt. So I set a circuit but i don't know does it work and if it is work what kind of mosfet shoul I choose. The circuit is here: https://www.hizliresim.com/a10chwg

Comment: Why so high frequency though? You may want to withhold selecting this answer until you’ve edited more information into your question- it’s quite possible you will get a more helpful answer than this one, and selecting an answer removes some incentive for others to add their two cents.

Comment: Thank you for your interest sir. I need this frequency for an experiment of water electrolysis. I need to check what happens when I increase the frequency sir that is why i need it. For the lower frequency between 0-1.3 MHz I know what happens but I need to investigate for higher frequencies.